# How to handle 500 errors from Google API

Tags: php, laravel, google-api

How can I handle google API errors? For example, the following script will get the screenshot from the website requested:

```
        $api_response = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" . $websiteURL . "&screenshot=true");
        $result = json_decode($api_response, true);
        $screenshot1 = $result['lighthouseResult']['audits']['final-screenshot']['details']['data'];
```

but if the domain doesn't exists google returns this error:

```
Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

How can I handle this error and create a custom error page for that?

My project is on Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with an if statement

```
if(($api_response = @file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" . $websiteURL . "&screenshot=true")) !== false) {
    //success
    $result = json_decode($api_response, true);
    $screenshot1 = $result['lighthouseResult']['audits']['final-screenshot']['details']['data'];
}
else{
    //do error stuff
}
```